# Online shiurim on the topic of religious OCD

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, adult-learning, psych-mentalhealth

Would anyone know of any online *Shiurim* on the topic of religion-related Obsessive Compulsive Disorder.

Comment: what do you mean by "Religious ocd"?

Comment: See this great summary https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/10/2010/religious_compulsions_and_fears_by_avigdor_bonchek/ of Avigdor Bonchek's "Religious Compulsions and Fears"

Comment: http://rechovot.blogspot.com/2014/03/judaism-and-obsessive-compulsive.html http://adderabbi.blogspot.com/2014/09/rav-asher-weiss-on-ocd.html

Answer (score 4):

Searching YUTorah for "OCD" produces [this list](http://www.yutorah.org/search/?s=OCD&sort=3) of 11 shiurim on the topic. The one of those shiurim that I've listened to was carefully researched from both the Torah and medical perspectives, at least two others are by people I would trust to be careful with these issues, and incidentally, 5 are given by doctors. They include *halacha* and *hashkafa* shiurim, and two shiurim about the [teshuva of Rav Asher Weiss regarding OCD](http://www.scribd.com/doc/238439231/rav-asher-weiss-s-responsum-on-obsessive-compulsive-disorder) mentioned in @Shalom's link above.

(Religion-focused Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder is also known as "[scrupulosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrupulosity)"; using that term may help you search for related articles, etc.)

Comment: The link in this answer to Rav Asher Weiss's teshuva no longer works. Does anyone have an updated link?